# Localising page title with angular-ui-router-title and angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate

I know there are many ways to create both static and dynamic page titles with angular, but the best way I've found so far is [angular-ui-router-title](https://github.com/nonplus/angular-ui-router-title).

Briefly, it works like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('a', {
    ...
    resolve: {
      $title: function () { return 'a title'; } 
    }
    ...
}
```

and in the view:

```
 <title ng-bind="$title"></title>
```

Now I'd like to get localisation working dynamically too, with [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate). When the user changes language in my application, an event is fired on the root scope and I use `$translate.use()` to change the language in use.

I figured I'd just be able to do this:

```
<title ng-bind-template="{{$title | translate}}"></title>
```

where the resolved title is now a translate key, and it would work, but it doesn't. Is there any other way I can get this translation to happen at runtime?